# How to take multiple integer inputs given in multiple lines?

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to take multiple newline integer inputs.

For example:

```
2
1 44 2 14
2 42 8 23
```

In the first line, it is given that there will be 2 lines of input.Then I need to take the each line in separate array.

I need to take the inputs from command line not from a file

Comment: Nice, you wait for three answers then change the question to make all three irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
numlines = int(input().strip())
for lineno in range(numlines):
    line = input().split()
    print(line)
```

Comment: Sorry but i need to take input from command line, not from some file

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = "" 
for i in xrange(5):
    lines+=input()+"\n" 
print (lines)
```

Or

```
lines = [] 
while True: 
     line = input() 
     if line: 
         lines.append(line) 
     else: 
         break 
print (lines)
text = '\n'.join(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

First take the first line that indicates how many more lines will be, and then save each line as a list of ints inside a list. You don't want to dynamically create lists (as new names) for each line, simply pack them in one big list:

```py
num_of_lines = int(input())

lines = []
for _ in range(num_of_lines):
    lines.append(list(map(int, input().split())))

print(lines)
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

And on your example input this prints:

```
[[1, 44, 2, 14], [2, 42, 8, 23]]
[1, 44, 2, 14]
[2, 42, 8, 23]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer